# setAdapter doesn't work on Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I currently have a Fragment Activity, but I am not able to get my adapter working.
In my Fragment Activity, i'm having an error on the setAdapter line.
Here is my Fragment:

```
package com.oneapp.tiradentes;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main4,container,false);

    ArrayList<Carro> carros = new ArrayList<Carro>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        Carro carro = new Carro();
        carro.setModelo("Carro "+(i + 1));
        carro.setMarca("Marca "+(i + 1));

        carros.add(carro);
    }

    ListView lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lv);
    lv.setAdapter(new CarroAdapter(this, carros));

    return rootView;
}
}
```

In this line that's show an error:

```
lv.setAdapter(new CarroAdapter(this, carros));
```

Please, someone can help me ?

My Adapter:
    package com.oneapp.tiradentes;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CarroAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Carro> lista;

public CarroAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Carro> lista){
    this.context = context;
    this.lista = lista;
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lista.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return lista.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Carro carro = lista.get(position);
    View layout;

    if(convertView == null){
LayoutInflater inflater =   (LayoutInflater)  context.getSystemService                  

(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.carros, null);
    }
    else{
        layout = convertView;
    }


    TextView modelo = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.t1);
    modelo.setText(carro.getModelo());

    TextView marca = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.t2);
    marca.setText(carro.getMarca());

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.iv);
    iv.setImageResource(carro.getCarroImagem(position));

    if(position % 2 == 0){
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    }

    return layout;
}

}
```

error:

```
carroAdapter (android.content.Context,       ArrayList<Carro>) in               

CarroAdapter cannot be applied to (com.oneapp.tiradentes.FragmentA ,   

ArrayList<Carro>)
```

Comment: What error showing ?

Comment: Post some code of your adapter class too. I think you're not calling constructor properly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lv);
```

Try using this:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv);
```

because `getView()` will be ready after method `onCreateView`

Answer (score 0):

Your `CarroAdapter` takes context as first parameter, and your are sending `this` from fragment class which means you are sending `FragmentA` instance. 
change it to

```
lv.setAdapter(new CarroAdapter(getActivity(), carros));
```

Also try to avoid keeping `Context` as a member, in your adapter you are using context only in

```
 LayoutInflater inflater =   (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

which you can replace with

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify code at this place:

```
    ListView lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lv);
  lv.setAdapter(new CarroAdapter(getActivity(),carros));
```

This is because the fragment does not contain any context; you have to pass activity here.